# Express the concept of "from" date "to" date in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timespan

I have a situation where the user can do something (like a post) only into a given timespan, like from <10 december 2010> to <5 march 2011>.

How do you suggest to express it in a rails model/database table? Is it better as a datetime + a timespan or should I use 2 datetime fields?

Thanks, I know the question could be stupid but maybe there is something that has analyzed it and find out something important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use two datetimes, as it saves you a calculation :)

Comment: Agree! Two datetimes are the way to go. So you are able to easily switch one or both of them at ease.

Comment: I was asking this because there is an important part to consider while using 2 dates: ok you save a calculation but you must always check that first date (from) is lesser than the other one (to).

Comment: Shouldn't that be done before you save the data to the db in the first place? With validations? Extend the ``validate`` method on the Model to check this serverside.

Comment: In HUGE systems where you have jobs that do database maintenance, for the sake of performance, you could add a "is_active" field that would indicate that it is currently valid. But I dought you will ever need that kind of performance ;-)